# r write a function to transform a one column based on second column

Tags: r

I created a fictitious data frame `a` such that `a = data.frame(b=1:10, c=sample(c("h","H","k","K"),10, replace = T))`

```
a
    b c
1   1 k
2   2 H
3   3 H
4   4 k
5   5 k
6   6 k
7   7 H
8   8 h
9   9 H
10 10 h
```

I want to write a simple function that will:

> multiply b by 1000 if c equal k or K, or multiply b by 100 if c equals h or H.

I found that the `transform` function is useful for this after searching the site but I still would like know how to write such a simple function. This is what I tried to do:

```
change_exp <- function(x){

    if(x[2] %in% c("h","H")) {
        x[1] <- x[1] * 100
    } else if(x[2] %in% c("k","K")){
        x[1] <- x[1] * 1000
    }
}
```

And I tried to run it `change_exp(a)` but to no avail.  My question is how can I write such a function.
Note I found that following will perform the desired manipulation:

```
transform( a,
           b = 
               ifelse( c %in% c("h","H"), b*100,
                ifelse( c %in% c("k","K"), b*1000, b)))
```

However I would like to get use to functional programming as well. Thanks

Comment: You can't use a logical vector that has length > 1 in an if statement.

Comment: @Bhail are you wanting to save the result to a new column in the dataframe or overwrite an existing column? Since R is a functional language, you are going to need to save the result somewhere after the computation

Comment: @Matthew in my code above I have `x[1] <- x[1] * 100` dose this not count? I am trying to read about R being a functional language right now, yet I would appreciate if you gave be a concrete example as well.  Thanks

Comment: @Bhail in this case it does not because you are doing that inside of the function call. The function call is making a copy of the original data and performing the calculation that you want to perform but that change is only occurring on the copy. You are trying to mutate the data.frame inside of the function which will not work. You would likely be better off creating a function which took two vectors as arguments and then calculated the resulting vector. You would then assign the value of the function result to the column you wanted to store the data in.

Comment: What @Ronak Shah is suggesting is closer to what you want.

Comment: @Bhail you want to assign the result of the calculation to a column of the data.frame. You cannot update the values of a data.frame inside of a function call. It goes against the nature of R. There are some libraries which allow you do to do it but this is not one of those circumstances.

Comment: Variation on a theme, but if you know you want to do this when building your data.frame, in `tibble::data_frame` you can reference earlier variables: `data_frame(b = 1:10, c = sample(c("h","H","k","K"), 10, replace = T), b2 = b * ifelse(tolower(c) == 'h', 100, 1000))`

Comment: or use math: `data_frame(b = 1:10, c = sample(c("h","H","k","K"), 10, replace = T), b2 = b * 100 * 10 ^ (tolower(c) == 'k'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a look-up table of some sort is often handy for this, and is very easily generalised to much larger samples without writing new code:

```
key <- data.frame(mult=c(1000,100), val=c("k","h"))
key
#  mult val
#1 1000   k
#2  100   h
key$mult[match(tolower(a$c),key$val)] * a$b
#[1]  100  200 3000 4000  500 6000 7000 8000 9000 1000
```

A named vector also works in a similar fashion, but is probably not as nice from a data structure perspective:

```
key <- setNames(c(1000,100), c("k","h"))
a$b * key[tolower(a$c)]
#   h    h    k    k    h    k    k    k    k    h 
# 100  200 3000 4000  500 6000 7000 8000 9000 1000
```

Comment: I was trying to think how to grasp how the look-up table works, how to think about in words:

Answer (score 2):

We can use vectorized `ifelse` here

```
a$b <- with(a, ifelse(tolower(c) == "k", b * 1000, b*100))
```

If there are values other than `k` and `h` we can use nested ifelse

```
with(a, ifelse(tolower(c) == "k", b * 1000, ifelse(tolower(c) == "h", b*100, b)))
```

---

We can apply the same logic with `transform`

```
transform(a, b = ifelse(tolower(c) == "k", b * 1000, b*100))
```

Comment: first time I've seen `tolower` in use and learned its usefulness.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another way you could do this is using `which`:

```
change_exp <- function(x){
    x[,1][which(x[,2] %in% c("h", "H"))] <- x[,1][which(x[,2] %in% c("h", "H"))] * 100
    x[,1][which(x[,2] %in% c("k","K"))] <- x[,1][which(x[,2] %in% c("k","K"))] * 1000
    return(x)
}
```

Comment: This would be the only way I've seen so for that a function could be put together for doing the said task.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[, b1 := b*100][tolower(c) == "k", b1 := b * 1000]
```

If we need to transform multiple values

```
key <- data.frame(c=c("k","K", "h", "H"), val = c(1000, 1000, 100, 100))
setDT(a)[key, b := b*val , on = "c"]
a
#       b c
# 1: 1000 k
# 2:  200 H
# 3:  300 H
# 4: 4000 k
# 5: 5000 k
# 6: 6000 k
# 7:  700 H
# 8:  800 h
# 9:  900 H
#10: 1000 h
```

---

Or another option is `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
   mutate(b = if_else(tolower(c)=="k", b * 1000, b * 100))
#      b c
#1  1000 k
#2   200 H
#3   300 H
#4  4000 k
#5  5000 k
#6  6000 k
#7   700 H
#8   800 h
#9   900 H
#10 1000 h
```

Comment: @ akrun Just as you were typing this I accepted the answer with look-up table, I was trying to grasp what exactly was going on with subset indexing in that answer as I have seen Hadley using it in one of his older talks.  And data.table is something else that I will go over and try to remember.  Thanks

Comment: @Bhail  I would use the lookup table with join when there are more than one value to replace as it is easier and faster compared to nested `ifelse`